# How to validate/clean() a unique=True field without using a ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

In a custom Form, how does one validate a Model's field's uniqueness (i.e., has `unique=True` set)?

I know that django's ModelForm automatically performs a `validate_unique()` function that is called within the BaseModelForm's `clean()` method -- so, when using ModelForm, this will be handled correctly (as it is in the Admin).

However, I am creating my own form from scratch and wonder how I can go about handling this myself?  I think my biggest stumbling block is knowing which object is attached to the form when the data is being cleaned ...

Some code:

```
class UserProfile(CreatedModifiedModel):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    display_name    = models.CharField('Display Name',max_length=30,
                        blank=True,unique=True)

class EditUserProfileForm(forms.Form):
    display_name    = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=30)

    # "notifications" are created from a different model, not the UserProfile
    notifications    = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                        label="Email Notifications",
                        required=False,
                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,)

    def clean_display_name(self):
        # how do I run my own validate_unique() on this form?
        # how do I know which UserProfile object I am working with?

    # more code follows, including the __init__ which sets up the notifications
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're making a custom form instead of a ModelForm?

Comment: i updated the code to show the "notifications" field I need that is from a different app but handled on the same EditUserProfileForm ... hope this makes sense.  I don't think I can make a ModelForm from multiple model sources ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unique validation is hard to get completely right, so I would recommend using a ModelForm anyways:

```
class EditUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # "notifications" are created from a different model, not the UserProfile
    notifications    = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                        label="Email Notifications",
                        required=False,
                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('display_name',)
```

Making a form from multiple models is not easy, but in this case you can just add the `notifications` field onto the ModelForm and pull it out of `.cleaned_data` as usual:

```
# view
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditUserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user_profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_profile = form.save()
        notifications = form.cleaned_data['notifications']
        # Do something with notifications.
```

That's how I would do it, but if you're set on validating unique yourself, you can always do something like:

```
def clean_display_name(self):
    display_name = self.cleaned_data['display_name']
    if UserProfile.objects.filter(display_name=display_name).count() > 0:
        raise ValidationError('This display name is already in use.')
    return display_name
```

There are two problems I see here. First, you can run into concurrency issues, where two people submit the same name, both pass unique checks, but then one gets a DB error. The other problem is that you can't edit a user profile because you don't have an ID to exclude from the search. You'd have to store it in your `__init__` and then use it in the cleaning:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    if 'instance' in kwargs:
        self.id = kwargs['instance'].id
    ...

def clean_display_name(self):
    display_name = self.cleaned_data['display_name']
    qs = UserProfile.objects.filter(display_name=display_name)
    if self.id:
        qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.id)
    if qs.count() > 0:
        raise ValidationError('This display name is already in use.')
    return display_name
```

But at that point you're just duplicating the logic in ModelForms.

Comment: Hey - thanks for that. I wasn't sure about adding fields to a ModelForm that don't correspond to the model ... But I will give this a try for starters. If I have problems will report back.

Answer (score 0):

Working Example !

I am using email as unique field

In models.py use below code

```
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

In forms.py use below code

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, required=True)

    def clean_email(self):
        user_id = self.cleaned_data['user'].id
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        obj = User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(id = user_id)
        if obj:
            raise forms.ValidationError('User with this email is already exists.Try a new email')
```