# Django admin: Unique email verification fails against self

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-admin

Hi Here's a snippet from my admin.py

```
#admin.py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email already used")
        return email

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I use this to check that a new user cannot be created with an email address already used. The problem is that when I edit an existing user the validation check fails, because there is a user with that mail address, but that's OK because it's the one I'm editing.

How can I tell the form validation to ignore the match against the current user?

Comment: May be in clean method, you can check for instance id (i'm not sure if thats available or not in that method).

Comment: Two questions (not related to the solution per se): 1. Why is the unregister needed (or is it)? and 2. Is there an advantage to doing the check here instead of adding a unique=True to the email field in the model? (Or perhaps "Is there a disadvantage to using unique=True as opposed to this solution?" since that's what I've been doing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exclude the current instance from your query:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("This email already used")
    return email
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much more better to validate uniqueness using `unique` on model field.

You can use custom `User` model with unique email constraint.

Look at this for more info about implementing unique validation on your own https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560617/527064